# Why is the following java code leads to compilation error

Tags: java, generics, type-systems

I am currently working on making my code contain more generics. I encountered a compilation error which looks quite complicated but which I was able to reduce to an equivalent error in the following code:

```
List<List<?>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Why this happens? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: I understood it myself. It might lead to hard to find errors in runtime. For example, we can write the following code:
    List<List<?>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    a.add(new ArrayList<List<Short>>());
which is obviously incorrect since might insert list of short in a place where list of integers is expected.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give a not too complex, but not yet oversimplified example?

Comment: The error which I encountered, basically boils down to the error which I described. So if I understand why the error in the message happens, I will understand why the typesystem was designed in this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instances of a generic class with different type parameters are not related, i.e. even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`, `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`, and even though `List<Integer>` is a subtype of `List<?>`, `List<List<Integer>>` is not a subtype of `List<List<?>>`.

Perhaps you are looking for

```
List<? extends List<?>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

The two sides have to match for the inner `List`:

```
List<List<?>> foo = new ArrayList<List<?>>();
foo.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Though this is rather silly as you've just defined a List of "Lists that can hold anything", and unless you know exactly what each is in that outer List, there's no way to divine it later due to type erasure.