# Why does the following cast lead to a compilation error?

Tags: java, generics, types, casting

I have the following code:

```
public static<F, S> void xyz() {
  class Pair<X, Y> {}    
  class Role<F> {}

  Map<?, List<Pair<?, ?>>> map = null;
  Role<F> role = null;

  List<Pair<F, S>> result = (List<Pair<F, S>>) map.get(role);
}
```

Unfortunately, Java complains about the cast on the last line. Why does this happen?

In my option, this is counterintuitive. A cast should be allowed in every place where there's a possibility of a correct type correspondence.

Comment: what's the expected return type?

Comment: You should provide the method signature as well - and maybe the class signature too (where did you specify F and S?).

Comment: I added more complete example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"A cast should be allowed in every place where there's a possibility of a correct type correspondence." In this case, there is NO possibility of a correct type correspondence.

An object can never be an instance of both `List<A>` and `List<B>`, if A and B are concrete and not the same, even if A is a subtype of B or whatever. For example, you cannot have an object that is both `List<String>` and `List<Object>`. There is (conceptually) a specific type parameter for each object. You have to understand this part first.

Your example is just the same -- `List<Pair<F, S>>` and `List<Pair<?, ?>>`. For the same reason as with String and Object above, an object that is of type `List<Pair<?, ?>>` can never also be `List<Pair<F, S>>`.

Update: More explanation in case it helps. @Konstantin: If you write `Pair<?, ?>`, then those type parameters at the top level, which are `?` (wildcards), are flexible. `Pair<T1, T2>` is compatible with `Pair<?, ?>`. However, in `List<Pair<?, ?>>`, the `?` is not at the top level. The type parameter at the top level is `Pair<?, ?>`, which is not a wildcard, and thus is not flexible. It doesn't matter that you happen to have `?` deeper down. If you have `List<? extends Pair<?, ?>>`, then the top level is a wildcard, and is flexible.

What you probably want is `List<? extends Pair<?, ?>>`. Perhaps it will help you to consider the difference between `List<Pair<?, ?>>` and `List<? extends Pair<?, ?>>`. `List<Pair<?, ?>>` says that this is a List, and it type parameter is *exactly* the type `Pair<?, ?>` (and nothing else, not `Pair<T1, T2>`, etc.). `List<? extends Pair<?, ?>>` says that this is a List, and it type parameter is something which is a subtype of `Pair<?, ?>` (and this includes `Pair<T1, T2>`).

Comment: Actually map.get(role) compiles. 

Here is my reasoning why the code is correct. ? extends is an existential type. It means that there exist T1 and T2 that for that instance of List<Pair<?, ?>> its actual type is List<Pair<T1, T2>>. So why can I specify which types T1 and T2 if I have information?

Comment: I reformulated my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274547/how-to-create-a-list-with-complex-structure-inside

Answer (score 1):

The cast doesn't make any sense. It is not the reverse of a widening cast.

A similar possible cast, where we have a wildcard argument:

```
List<String> ls;
List<?> cast = ls;
```

In that case, I can't subsequently add an `Integer` to the `ls`/`cast` object.

```
cast.add(Integer.valueOf(0)); // Not going to work.
```

Where the generic argument itself is a generic with a wildcard, the situation is very different.

```
List<List<String>> strses;
List<List<?>> cast = strses; // Suppose this actually worked.
List<Integer> ints;
List<?> wildInts = ints;
cast.add(0, wildInts); // Good.
List<String> wasInts = strses.get(0); // Oops!!
```

Comment: You examples don't contain any cast expression. I understand why these examples don't work, see another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152302/why-is-the-following-java-code-leads-to-compilation-error

However, we are able to explicitly cast to String from Object and this might have some sense in some situation. IMO, the same is with cast from List<Pair<?, ?>> to List<Pair<X, Y>>. We might now from some other parts of the program that this list is actually a Pair<X, Y>

Comment: I reformulated my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274547/how-to-create-a-list-with-complex-structure-inside

Answer (score 1):

When an object is created, it has an exact type. This type might be `ArrayList<Pair<F, S>>` which of course is a subtype of `List<Pair<F, S>>`. This however, as Tom pointed out, is not a subtype of `List<Pair<?,?>>`. So the only way your cast would be correct was if there was an unsound cast somewhere else. If generics were reified at some point, either your cast or that unsound cast would break. That's the rationale for why that cast is rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are not a completely new type system. Internally, it's all based on casts (because of the byte code (backward) compatibility).

Extending Tom's answer, let's do the simplest possible examples:

```
List<? extends Object> genericList; // List<?> is short for List<? extends Object>
List<String> concreteList = new LinkedList<String>();

genericList = concreteList;
concreteList = (List<String>) genericList; //(caution: uncheck cast)
```

So, this works since String extends Object. Let's go on step further and do lists of lists:

```
List<List<?>> listOfGenericLists;
List<List<String>> listOfStrings = new LinkedList<List<String>>();
//does not work "only because" String extends Object:
listOfGenericLists = listOfStrings; //compile error
```

This is the same error as in your example. The intuition is to say that this should work because String extends Object and therefore `List<String>` should extend `List<Object>`. Well, this is not the case. You probably would not have been surprised about this:
    List> listOfIntegers;
    listOfIntegers = listOfStrings; //also compile error

Let's see what happens, when we make the intuition explicit. Let's actually extend from the lists:

```
List<? extends List<?>> genericListOfLists = new LinkedList<List<?>>();
List<? extends List<String>> genericListOfStringLists = new LinkedList<List<String>>();
genericListOfLists = listOfStrings;
genericListOfStringLists = listOfStrings;
listOfStrings = (List<List<String>>) genericListOfLists; //(caution: unchecked cast)
listOfStrings = (List<List<String>>) genericListOfStringLists; // works as before (caution: uncheck cast)
```

Ah-ha! Now intuition is back on the track. Right?
Actually no:

```
List<? extends List<Integer>> listOfIntegerLists;
listOfIntegerLists = (List<List<Integer>>) genericListOfLists; //(caution: uncheck cast)
listOfIntegerLists = (List<List<Integer>>) genericListOfStringLists; //OUCH (no compilation error just an unchecked cast!)
```

The reason is - as said before: From a type point of view all generics are the same and casting works on a type level.

I can recommend [Java Generics and Collections](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527754.do) by Maurice Naftalin and Philip Wadler (O'Reilly) for details.

Comment: I reformulated my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274547/how-to-create-a-list-with-complex-structure-inside

Answer (score -1):

You want casting generic instance of list to another generic instance of list:

```
List<Pair<?, ?>> ==>> List<Pair<F, S>>
```

You cant solve this by folowing way:

```
List<Pair<?, ?>> result = (List<Pair<?, ?>>) map.get(role);
```

Comment: Actually I know how to workaround the problem. I can change the last line to (List<Pair<F, S>>) (List) map.get(role); and everything will be fine. What I want is to understand why the following code is incorrect from a point of view of a language designer.

Comment: What mean this :public static<F, S> void xyz()? because method return type is void so what is generic mean?i don't understand. Please expmain this.

Comment: In Java it's possible to add generic parameters to methods. Generics mean nothing, it's just an example.

Comment: Actually i know it's possible in java, but don't understand its benefits?

Comment: I reformulated my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274547/how-to-create-a-list-with-complex-structure-inside