# How to create a list with complex structure inside

Tags: java, generics

I have the following two classes:

```
class Key<T1, T2> {}
class Pair<F, S> {}
```

I want to create a map from `Key<T1, T2>` to `List<Pair<T1, T2>>` where T1 and T2 are different for each map's entry. I am trying to implement it this way:

```
class KeyToListMap {
  private Map<Key<?, ?>, List<Pair<?, ?>>> myItems = new HashMap<Key<?, ?>, List<Pair<?, ?>>>();


  public<T1, T2> List<Pair<T1, T2>> getList(Key<T1, T2> key) {
    if (!myItems.containsKey(key)) {
      myItems.put(key, new ArrayList<Pair<T1, T2>>());
    }
    return (List<Pair<T1, T2>>) myItems.get(key);
  }
}
```

However I got two type errors:

```
put(test.Key<?,?>,java.util.List<test.Pair<?,?>>) in java.util.Map<test.Key<?,?>,java.util.List<test.Pair<?,?>>> cannot be applied to (test.Key<T1,T2>,java.util.ArrayList<test.Pair<T1,T2>>)

inconvertible types
found   : java.util.List<test.Pair<?,?>>
required: java.util.List<test.Pair<T1,T2>>
```

How can I express this in Java without resorting to using raw types?

Comment: The `<?>` is the *unknown type* and that type is different from any other type. That's why the types are inconvertible. It is a common misunderstanding to think, that `?` is a placeholder for any type

Comment: 2Andreas_d. I understand it. But how can I express what I want?

Comment: BTW: have you heard about the KISS principle? No offense, but 1 year after you code is done will you be able (expect others to be able) to actually understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
? extends
```

in Map declaration

Comment: Where exactly should I do it?

Comment: In "Map declaration" (as I mentioned). private Map<Key<?, ?>, List<? extends Pair<?, ?>>> myItems .... <?> is the unknown type so you need to provide some kind of abstract class or even Marker interface to instruct the compiler what to expect.

Comment: I used the same solution myself (see below) but it seems quite a hack. Pair doesn't have any subtypes and there's no point in doing so.

Comment: @Konstantin Solomatov: Yes, the class Pair may not have any concrete subclasses. But the type `Pair<?,?>` does have subtypes -- you have to consider the subtyping relation of parameterized types. `Pair<T1,T2>` is a subtype of `Pair<?,?>`, because `Pair<T1,T2>` is assignable to `Pair<?,?>`. `Pair<T1,?>` is also a subtype of `Pair<?,?>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. The problem here is that you want the map value type to *depend* on the key type. The use of generics here is actually not the issue. For example, there is no way to declare that a map has integer keys always associated with integer values and string keys associated with string values. You will always have to type the keys and values as a common supertype (probably Object) and cast to the expected type.

Comment: So could you give an example of how I should rewrite the code above to make it compilable?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it like this:

```
class Key<T1, T2> {
}

class Pair<F, S> {

}

class KeyToListMap {
  private Map<Key<?, ?>, List<? extends Pair<?, ?>>> myItems = new HashMap<Key<?, ?>, List<? extends Pair<?, ?>>>();

  public<T1, T2> List<Pair<T1, T2>> getList(Key<T1, T2> key) {
    if (!myItems.containsKey(key)) {
      myItems.put(key, new ArrayList<Pair<T1, T2>>());
    }
    return (List<Pair<T1, T2>>) myItems.get(key);
  }
}
```

However it's kind of hack. Does anyone know a better answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the map as below

```
private Map<Key<T1, T2>, List<Pair<F, S>>> myItems = new HashMap<Key<T1, T2>, List<Pair<F, S>>>();
```

Comment: I can't T1 and T2 are type parameters of a method, not of a class.

Comment: I'd thought T1 and T2 are really class.If it is not,try `? extends T1` instead